# How can I add more fragments of the same class to a Layout?

Tags: android, fragment

I have the following code:

```
FragmentA myFragment = new FragmentA(); 

transaction.add(R.id.my_fragment_container, myFragment);

myFragment = new FragmentA(); 

transaction.add(R.id.my_fragment_container, myFragment);

transaction.commit();
```

So what I want that happens is, that this will create 2 fragments.
One of the both should be placed under the other one.

My layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/my_fragment_container"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

So what do I have to do that 2 Fragments were added and one of them is under the other one?

regards simon

Comment: what do you mean "placed among themselves"?

Comment: Do you only want two, or do you want to make it run-time determined?

Comment: overall about 10. but I want to add theme in code while run-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make the following code a separate XML layout file:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

2) Inflate it using code and grab the id of the inflated layout.

3) Programmatically add the inflated layout to the layout with `id=my_fragment_container`.

4) Add the fragment to the FragmentManager with the inflated layout id.

```
FragmentA myFragment = new FragmentA(); 
transaction.add(layout_id, myFragment);
```

I believe that this should work, cheers.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question... I want to add the Fragments to the Layout with android:id="@+id/my_fragment_container" and this fragments I want to add should be generated by code and placed one over another

Comment: Okay, I don't understand how is that different? Instead of inflating the `LinearLayout`, inflate a `FrameLayout`, and instead of adding the inflated layout to the main layout, add it to the `id/my_fragment_container` layout. And the rest of the steps are the same.